# How to type a property from an array of objects when adding them programmatically

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type countryListProps = {
  dial_code: string;
  code: string;
  name: string;
  lower?: string;
};

const countryList: countryListProps[] = [
  {
    'dial_code': 'somevalue',
    'code': 'somevalue',
    'name': 'Somevalue',
  },
  {
    'dial_code': 'somevalue',
    'code': 'somevalue',
    'name': 'Somevalue',
  },
];

const toLower = {} as countryListProps[];
for (let i=0; i<countryList.length; i++) {
  const country: countryListProps = countryList[i];
  toLower[country.code] = country;
  country.lower = country.name.toLowerCase();    // adding other propery 'lower'
}
```

Typescript gives me :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

my goal is just to add 'lower' as a property with type as a string, so my result object on each would look something like:

```
{
    'dial_code': '+756',
    'code': 'something',
    'name': 'UpperCase',
    'lower': 'lowercase of name',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you just use

```
let newArr = countryList.map((i)=>{
 return {
  ...i,
  lower:'hello',
 }
})
```

instead of

```
const toLower = {} as countryListProps[];
for (let i=0; i<countryList.length; i++) {
 const country: countryListProps = countryList[i];
 toLower[country.code] = country;
 country.lower = country.name.toLowerCase();    // adding other propery 'lower'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
type countryListProps = {
      dial_code: string;
      code: string | number;     # code will accept both string and number
      name: string;
      lower?: string;
    };
```

Try declaring `toLower` as:

```
const toLower: {[key: string]: countryListProps} = {};
```

Comment: but key could be anything? no?

Comment: @swoopy I have updated the `countryListProps` type declaration. Except boolean (I don't think you can provide boolean as key in typescript), you can provide anything as a key including `undefined` and `null`